# Loading a model in a cron file, in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, cron

I have a directory called cron, inside my app directory.  In the cron directory, I have put my cron file.  How do I access the model inside my cron file?

Which is the best place to put my cron file?

edit:
I'm trying to execute the cron file, directly like ruby cron.rb

Comment: clarify, please. You have an active record model inside app/cron? Or you want to load a cron file stored at app/cron from a regular model?

Comment: the model is in /app/models folder and the cron is in /app/cron folder.  I am not able to access my model in the cron file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming what you want to do is run a script (which you have saved in the `cron` folder) as a cronjob, but you want it to load the Rails environment, including access to your ActiveRecord models, before it runs.

If this is the case, what you want to use is the `script/runner` script in your Rails app, supplying it with the name of the script you want to run, e.g.

```
script/runner cron/my_cron_script.rb
```

If you want to add this as a cronjob, add it to your crontab as follows. Edit your crontab with the `crontab -e` command and put something like the following there:

```
* * * * * /path/to/my/app/script/runner /path/to/my/app/cron/my_cron_script.rb
```